# ObjectToJsonTransformer in Spring 4 throws NPE when having null values

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-integration

I am processing a JSON message with spring integration. The message can vary in format and I am interested in a particular sub-object (called `payload`) of the whole JSON I receive. I match the Java class for that sub-object against another field (`type`) from the received message in order to know how to deserialize it.

To achieve this, I convert the message to a `java.lang.Object` using `<int:json-to-object-transformer type="java.lang.Object" />` - this will in fact convert the initial JSON to a `LinkedMap` object which I can query for fields and perform filtering and routing within my spring integration xml - for example:

```
<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="jsonInputChannel" ignore-send-failures="false" default-output-channel="fallbackChannel">
  <int:recipient 
    channel="validInputChannel" 
    selector-expression="payload.containsKey('type') and payload.containsKey('payload')"/>
</int:recipient-list-router>
```

In the above the `payload` is treated as a `Map` object. Then I extract the relevant object I need to further transform into a specific Java class:

```
<int:chain input-channel="validInputChannel" output-channel="objectResolveChannel">
    <int:transformer expression="payload.get('payload')" />
    <int:object-to-json-transformer />
</int:chain>
```

Here I am getting a NPE when the payload propery of the message looks like `{"field1": null, "field2": "something", ....}`

I had a look at the Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE source code and I can see that `ObjectToJsonTransformer` calls `this.jsonObjectMapper.populateJavaTypes(headers, message.getPayload());`
This in order calls the method implementation in `JsonObjectMapperAdapter`, which is the following:

```
public void populateJavaTypes(Map<String, Object> map, Object object) {
    map.put(JsonHeaders.TYPE_ID, object.getClass());
    if (object instanceof Collection && !((Collection) object).isEmpty()) {
        map.put(JsonHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_ID, ((Collection) object).iterator().next().getClass());
    }
    if (object instanceof Map && !((Map) object).isEmpty()) {
        map.put(JsonHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_ID, ((Map) object).values().iterator().next().getClass());
        map.put(JsonHeaders.KEY_TYPE_ID, ((Map) object).keySet().iterator().next().getClass());
    }
}
```

You can see that when the object is treated like a Map instance, the code uses `getClass()` on the first element of the map values, but this of course can be `null` and hence the NPE is thrown.

We were using Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE together with Spring Integration 2.2.6.RELEASE previously and the same Spring integration XML  configuration was working perfectly. As far as I know the problematic code above was not present in Spring 3.

Could someone suggest a nice workaround for this issue or a way to get back to the Spring 3 behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug; I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4045).

The only work-around, I think, is to fix the bug locally (subclass `ObjectToJsonTransformer`, fixing `doTransform()` by removing the `populateJavaTypes` call) and replace the `<object-to-json-transformer/>` with a normal `<transformer/>` referencing your bean.

Populating the java type headers was [added in 3.0](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2809).

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is the working approach for us.

Comment: Great - the bug is fixed and 4.2.7 should be release in the next week or so.